# SQL Select rows based on distinct column value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return postcode data for every country in our order table, this should be a straightforward query but I can't quite get it to work. The query executes fine but every row of the result is just:

- `POSTCODE` | `COUNTRY` | id < the country id

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 'POSTCODE' as billing_postcode, 'COUNTRY' as Title, billing_country_id
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Order]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Country]
ON country_id = billing_country_id
GROUP BY billing_country_id
```

Below is an example of the output that I'm getting: -

[image]

Why is it not returning the postcode + country? Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

Thanks

edit*

Basic Order table structure:

> OrderId | billing_postcode | billing_country_id

Basic Country table structure:

> country_id | Title

Comment: You're using apostrophes, which create just strings. Rewrite start of your query as: "SELECT POSTCODE as billing_postcode, COUNTRY as Title ..."

Answer (score 2):

You've selected the string `PostCode` and `Country` not the actual columns.

```
SELECT POSTCODE as 'billing_postcode', COUNTRY as 'Title', billing_country_id
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Order]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Country]
ON country_id = billing_country_id
GROUP BY billing_country_id
```

From your edit it seems that you need to switch the columns/alias around:

```
SELECT billing_postcode AS 'POSTCODE', Title as 'Country', billing_country_id
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Order]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Country]
ON country_id = billing_country_id
```

Comment: I thought it might be something simple like this however I then receive a second error that 'POSTCODE' etc... is not a valid column name

Comment: @DGibbs - what's your table structure? Replace POSTCODE with the exact column name

Comment: Sorry I should have pointed that out, I'll edit the question with the table structure. For now, `billing_postcode` and `Title` are columns from `Order` and `Country`. Doing this I get an error complaining that the columns are not contained within an aggregate function or the group by

Comment: Thanks, yes that is how I originally constructed the query but it was complaining that `billing_postcode` and `Title` are not in an aggregate function or group by clause. Adding them to the group by then defeats the purpose of trying to get the distinct postcodes as it will just return everything

Comment: @DGibbs - remove the GROUP BY.

Comment: If I remove the group by then it will return postcodes for the same countries whereas I need postcodes on a per country basis which is what the group by billing_country_id is for. It should only return one row for each country

Comment: Solved this by adding `MAX(billing_postcode), MAX(Title)` etc.. to the select

Comment: @DGibs - I'd say this was more of a hack as `MAX` returns the MAXIMUM in the expression.  `MAXIMUM` post code and country don't really make that much sense in this context.

Comment: Yeah definitely a hack but it did give me the results I needed. Is there any reason why the: `POSTCODE as 'billing_postcode'` etc... was not accepted by the group by? I've used group by in this way before with no issue

Comment: @DGibbs - `billing_postcode` is your column, `POSTCODE` is the alias.  You were trying to `SELECT PostCode AS `billing_postcode` where it should be: `SELECT billing_postcode AS PostCode`

Comment: Yep, but this complains that the `billing_postcode`/`title` columns are not contained within the group by

Answer (score 1):

Do like this. Remove apostrophes from column name and instead use it in alias part

```
SELECT POSTCODE as 'billing_postcode', COUNTRY as 'Title', billing_country_id
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Order]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Country]
ON country_id = billing_country_id
GROUP BY billing_country_id
```

Comment: Please see the comments on darrens answer, this does the same thing